# Google Map, re-size and re-center map with waypoints.js

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, maps

Before anyone says this question has been asked and answered, I would like to say yes and no. I have done quite an extensive search on stackoverflow and tried playing around with what I found but have still not come right.

I have built a single-page scroll site and have used waypoints.js to trigger css3 animations on scroll points. I have a page with a google maps script I found a while back that lets the user enter their location and the map will show directions to the pre-set marker.

### Problem A

the parent div for the google maps directions was set to display: none; and display: block; once the waypoint was reached, this posed the problem of the map breaking and only loading the top corner, now this was easy to research and I figured out how to use it in my code to fix that problem.

### Problem B

I then had the problem of where the map was no longer centering on my marker and I have done the research and found some bits of code here and there but none of it is working in my situation. I need to trigger both the resize function and centering function after my waypoints trigger is done.

EDIT: Live website is here: dreamsynk.com/rosewater click on "The Studio"

### Code

GOOGLE MAPS SCRIPT I FOUND:

```
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8333406,18.6470022);
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng, 
        map: map, 
        title:"Get Directions"
    }); 
}
function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("routeStart").value;
    var end = "-33.8333406,18.6470022";
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            if (status == 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
                alert('No route could be found between the origin and destination.');
            } else if (status == 'UNKNOWN_ERROR') {
                alert('A directions request could not be processed due to a server error. The request may succeed if you try again.');
            } else if (status == 'REQUEST_DENIED') {
                alert('This webpage is not allowed to use the directions service.');
            } else if (status == 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT') {
                alert('The webpage has gone over the requests limit in too short a period of time.');
            } else if (status == 'NOT_FOUND') {
                alert('At least one of the origin, destination, or waypoints could not be geocoded.');
            } else if (status == 'INVALID_REQUEST') {
                alert('The DirectionsRequest provided was invalid.');                   
            } else {
                alert("There was an unknown error in your request. Requeststatus: \n\n"+status);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

MY WAYPOINTS.JS FUNCTION THAT IS BREAKING THE MAP (location div being the parent wrapper for my google maps directions script):

```
jQuery('.studio-page').waypoint(function() {
jQuery('.kickass-studio').addClass( 'show animated bounceInLeft' );
jQuery('.location').addClass( 'show animated bounceInRight' );
jQuery('.geo-address').addClass( 'show animated bounceInDown' );

google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); 
map.setCenter(center);

},
{
offset: '10%'
});
```

Now this part is working:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

But this part is not:

```
map.setCenter(center);
```

I have tried using this as well before the jQuery document ready function:

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8333406,18.6470022);
```

HERE IS MY HTML:

```
<div class="location">
                <!-- google maps -->
                <div class="map">
                    <span class="area-local">
                        <span class="icon-location local-inner"></span>
                        <span class="geo-address geo-one">01 Sher Street, Durbanville, 7550</span>
                        <span class="geo-address geo-two">62 Roeland Street, Cape Town</span>
                    </span>
                    <!-- Route Planner -->
                    <div class="route">
                        <span>Enter your location</span>
                        <form action="/routebeschrijving" onsubmit="calcRoute();return false;" id="routeForm">
                            <input type="text" class="plan-box" id="routeStart" name="location" value="" placeholder="Location here">
                            <input type="submit" class="plan-btn" value="Get Directions" name="find">
                        </form>
                        <a href="#directions" class="lightbox instructions">View full directions</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Directions Lightbox -->
                    <div class="panel" id="directions">
                        <div id="directionsPanel" class="panel-inner"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="map-inner map-one" id="map"></div>
                    <div class="map-inner map-two"></div>

                </div>
            </div><!-- END map wrapper -->
```

Keep in mind before you vote this question down - my javascript is terrible, and to be honest I have no idea what's happening above, I just play around until things work. I have battled with this for hours and hours. I am just not coming right.

Comment: It would be useful to have a demo page for people to play with - codepen.io etc are useful for this.

Comment: Live website is here: http://dreamsynk.com/rosewater click on "The Studio"